# Chart is not getting displayed

Tags: d3.js

I am porting my working code from `d3 v3` to `d3 v5`.

d3 v3 solution (working):
https://plnkr.co/edit/AtiSa0JiMgQgogGe

d3 v5 solution (not working):
https://plnkr.co/edit/Y6h2gkyj08FNOHop

I have changed all the script to the latest version and changed the syntax. Now I am  not getting any error in the `console` window but the graph is not getting displayed.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing the projection as pointed by a user in the community group.

```
proj.scale(1290);
proj.translate([-1555, 862]);
```

It was getting projected outside so I was unable to see it.